# Binary search on an array giving wrong value

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

I'm doing a binary search on an array. But somethings to be off. It returns -1 as if the target is not being found but it is in the array. 
ex: when I put the key at 555 it returns the correct index but when I try with the example below with 8 it returns -1..

```
public class bSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {9,5,2,5,7,8,3,22,555};
        int key = 8;

        System.out.println(searchForNum(nums,0,nums.length-1,key));
    }

    private static int searchForNum(int[] arr,int first, int last, final int target) {
        int middle= (first+last)/2;

        if(last < first) {
            return -1;
        }

        if(arr[middle]== target)
            return middle;
        else if(target < arr[middle]) {
            return searchForNum(arr,first,middle-1,target);
        } else {
            return searchForNum(arr,middle+1,last,target);
        }  
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you step through the code in your IDE debugger?

Comment: A binary search only works if your list/array is sorted, otherwise it can't.

Answer (score 9):

The reason why binary search works is that the search interval is ordered. You are passing an unordered interval, which leads to search errors.

Call [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) on your data array before searching:

```
int[] nums = {9,5,2,5,7,8,3,22,555};
Arrays.sort(nums);
```

Comment: ahhh yes ! completely forgot. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** do binary search without sorting the list/array that you want to search on it

please read this for more info [binary-search](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/).

you need to modified your `main` method to be

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {9,5,2,5,7,8,3,22,555};
        int key = 8;
        Arrays.sort(nums); // sort the array 
        System.out.println(searchForNum(nums,0,nums.length-1,key));
    }
```